# Force Identity Server child application to refresh claims

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, claims

I have a parent web application which uses identity server to authenticate users across a suite of other web applications which act as children of that parent app.

We utilize a profile service within the parent application to set user claims which can be used with the child application. This profile service is registered with Identity Server on startup by using `IdentityServerBuilderExtensionsAdditional.AddProfileService`.

Within the user claims we store some user preferences for easy access within our child applications. Recently we added functionality within the parent application to allow users to directly update these preferences.

Unfortunately these updates do not seem to apply until the user's token is refreshed. This can be up to 5 minutes. There doesn’t seem to be any way for me to broadcast to the child applications that something has changed within the parent.

How can I, within the parent application, force the child applications to refresh their claims by making them call that user profile service?

---

I have tried logging the user out then back in e.g.

```cs
await SignOut();
await SignIn(user, rememberMe);
```

Interestingly this actually seems to work locally on my development machine, but once deployed to production environments this does not work. But I have not been able to determine any difference between my configuration and the production configuration. So, I am looking for a more robust way to force child apps to call this user profile service early.

Comment: Are you using jwt or reference token for access tokens?

Comment: @MisirJafarov JWT's

Comment: Could you try using reference tokens? The difference is that jwt tokens contains user claims. If you change something you need to re-issue jwt token. But i think reference token reads claims from db. So you might have a chance to update claims remotely without changing token's itself. (PS: changing token type might logout all users from the application)

Comment: It would be doable, but unfortunately, I think we might need to change quite a bit of infrastructure to make this possible. It might be less work for us to not store the user preferences in the claims and use an alternative way to get the info down to child applications. E.g. an API endpoint with web hooks to communicate the change has happened. Thank you for the suggestion, I wasn't aware of that different behaviour between the different types of tokens.

Comment: Check out: https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/